# Infimum of lower semicontinuous functions

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functional-analysis, analysis, measure-theory

The following proposition is from the book Nicolae Dinculeanu Integration on Locally Compact Spaces:

Let $H$ and $K$ be two compact Hausdorff spaces and $\alpha$ a continuous mapping of $H$ onto $K$. If $h\geq 0$ is a lower semicontinuous function on $H$ then the function $g(s)=\inf_{\alpha(t)=s}h(t)$ is lower semicontinuous on $K$.

If $\alpha$ is one-to-one then it is not that hard to prove this proposition, but $\alpha$ here is not necessary one-to-one, can anyone suggest a proof?

The following proof is from the author, the bold text is where I get confused, does the author do the quotient relation so we can change the $\alpha$ to be one-to-one? And it seems that the condition that $h\geq 0$ is redundant in the following proof.

We remark first that for every point $s\in K$ there exists a point $t_{s}\in H$ such that $\alpha(t_{s})=s$ and $g(s)=h(t_{s})$. In fact, $\{s\}$ is a closed set in $K$ and $\alpha$ is continuous on $H$, therefore $\alpha^{-1}(s)$ is closed in $H$ and hence compact. Since $h$ is lower semicontinuous and $\alpha^{-1}(s)$ is compact, there exists a point $t_{s}\in \alpha^{-1}(s)$ such that $h(t_{s})=\inf_{\alpha(t)=s}h(t)$, hence $g(s)=h(t_{s})$.

Let now $a$ be an arbitrary real number and prove that the set $A=\{s\in K: g(s)>a\}$ is open. It will then follow that $g$ is lower semicontinuous. Let $s_{0}\in A$. We have $g(s_{0})>a$, therefore $h(t)>a$ for every $t\in\alpha^{-1}(s_{0})$. Since $h$ is lower semicontinuous, there exists a neighbourhood $V$ of $\alpha^{-1}(s_{0})$ such that $h(t)>a$ for every $t\in V$.

**In addition, we can consider the set $V$ saturated for the equivalence relation $\alpha(t)=\alpha(t')$. Then $\alpha(V)$ is a neighbourhood of $s_{0}$.**

For every $s\in\alpha(V)$ there exists $t\in\alpha^{-1}(s)$ such that $h(t)=g(s)$. Therefore, we have $g(s)>a$ for every $s\in\alpha(V)$, hence $A$ is open.

Answer (score 2):

I have looked for several posts, and I think the following should be a correct proof.

To prove that $g$ is lower semicontinuous, it is sufficient to prove that $B=\{k\in K: g(k)\leq a\}$ is closed for each real number $a$. Now let $(s_{\delta})$ be a net in $B$ such that $s_{\delta}\rightarrow s$ for some $s\in K$. We need to show that $s\in K$. To this end, we can find a corresponding net $(t_{\delta})$ such that $\alpha(t_{\delta})=s_{\delta}$ and $g(s_{\delta})=h(t_{\delta})$. Since $H$ is compact, there is some convergent subnet $(t_{\delta_{\eta}})$ of $(t_{\delta})$ such that $t_{\delta_{\eta}}\rightarrow t$ for some $t\in H$. Since $h$ is lower semicontinuous and $h(t_{\delta_{\eta}})\leq a$, we deduce that $h(t)\leq a$. On the other hand, as $\alpha$ is continuous, we have $\alpha(t_{\delta_{\eta}})\rightarrow\alpha(t)$. Since $K$ is Hausdorff, we have $\alpha(t)=s$, so $g(s)\leq h(t)\leq a$.